# H2 で Data conversion error converting というエラーが出る

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

画像の + からデータを追加したいのですが、spring 上の H2 で Blank が許されずに
"Data conversion error converting" とエラーが出ます。

type を Integer にしているところにこのエラーが出るようです。

#### 環境

・spring (STS)

#### 参考

**H2:**

[image: H2]

**STS:**

[image: STS]

Comment: ご質問を [edit] して、どうなさりたいのかまで書いてくださいませんでしょうか。想定される挙動は何でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

insertしようとしている値の型がカラムの型と異なっているため発生しています。

添付画像内に表示されているSQLが見切れているので正確なところは分かりませんが、質問文から察するに`integer`型のカラムにから文字列`''`をinsertしようとしていると思われます。

この場合、設定すべきは`null`です。

---

実行例:

```sql
create table my_table(my_column integer);
insert into my_table(my_column) values('');
insert into my_table(my_column) values(null);
```

結果:

```
create table my_table(my_column integer);
更新数: 0
(1 ms)

insert into my_table(my_column) values('');
データ変換中にエラーが発生しました "'' (MY_TABLE: ""MY_COLUMN"" INTEGER)"
Data conversion error converting "'' (MY_TABLE: ""MY_COLUMN"" INTEGER)"; SQL statement:
insert into my_table(my_column) values('') [22018-200] 22018/22018 (ヘルプ)

insert into my_table(my_column) values(null);
更新数: 1
(0 ms)
```